# Symbolic Z Transform with Kronecker Delta

Tags: matlab, transform, signal-processing, symbolic-math

I am trying to plot the function that uses `kroneckerDelta` resulting from the following code. I tried many ways to plot the deltas, but nothing is working. I tried `fplot` and converting the `S` variable to a double before plotting. But nothing actually worked.

```
close all;clear all;clc; %#ok<*CLSCR>
syms y(n) x(n) H(Z) z
H(Z) = 5*x + 2*x*z^-2 + 3*x*z^-1;
h(n) = iztrans(H(Z), z, n)
S = subs(h(n), {x}, {1})
```

The output is:

```
h(n) = 5*x(n)*kroneckerDelta(n, 0) + 3*x(n)*kroneckerDelta(n - 1, 0) + 2*x(n)*kroneckerDelta(n - 2, 0)


S = 3*kroneckerDelta(n - 1, 0) + 2*kroneckerDelta(n - 2, 0) + 5*kroneckerDelta(n, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show how you're trying to plot so it's impossible to say what you're doing wrong. However, due to the discrete nature of the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), you should probably use the [`stem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html) function for your plots. There's no need to explicitly convert to floating point, but you do need to substitute in your values for `n`:

```
syms n;
S = 3*kroneckerDelta(n - 1, 0) + 2*kroneckerDelta(n - 2, 0) + 5*kroneckerDelta(n, 0);
N = -5:5;
S2 = subs(S,n,N);
stem(N,S2);
```

Another option is to use [`matlabFunction`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) to convert the symbolic expression to a numeric function:

```
syms n;
S = 3*kroneckerDelta(n - 1, 0) + 2*kroneckerDelta(n - 2, 0) + 5*kroneckerDelta(n, 0);
S2 = matlabFunction(S);
N = -5:5;
stem(n,S2(N));
```

Both options produce a plot that looks like this:
[image: stem plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made me understand some vague concepts with your answer. Thanks again